# $lookup when foreign field is an array

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collections.

**Sports**:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Football",
    "slots" : {
    "0" : {
        "div_id" : 1,
        "description" : "5x5"
    },
    "1" : {
        "div_id" : 2,
        "description" : "7x7"
    }
 })
```

**Booking**:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "spot" : 'SPOT1',
    "date" : ISODate("2018-11-13T10:04:45.000Z"),
    "slots" : [ 
        {
            "booking_id" : 142,
            "slot_id" : 23,
             ...
        }]
}
```

I want to show the booking details. While joining two collections, sport details cannot be fetched.

I tried this:

```
     $bookData  =   Booking::raw(function($collection) use($request) {
                   ....
            return $collection->aggregate([
               ['$lookup' => ['from'=>'spots', 'localField'=>'spot_id', 'foreignField'=>'id', 'as'=>'spot_data']],
               ['$lookup' => ['from'=>'sports_items', 'localField'=>'slots.slot_id', 'foreignField'=>'slot_divisions.div_id', 'as'=>'sports_data']],
               ['$unwind'  =>'$slots'],
               ['$project' => [
                    'booking_id'=>'$slots.booking_id',
                    'date'=>'$date',
                    'sports_data.item_name'=>'$sports_data.item_name',
                    'sports_data.item_icon'=>'$sports_data.item_icon',
                ]],

            ]);
        });
```

Im getting the response:

```
"sports_data": []
```

Can someone help me with this?

**Update :**
I tried pipe lining in look up as follows. But still empty result

```
 ['$lookup' => ['from'=>'sports_items', 'localField'=>'slots.slot_id', 'foreignField'=>'slot_divisions.div_id', 'as'=>'sports_data']],
```

**changed to**

```
      ['$lookup' => [
                    'from'=>'sports_items_collection',
                     'pipeline' =>[
                         ['$unwind'  =>'$slot_divisions'],
                         ['$match'=>["slots.slot_id"=>['$eq'=> ["slot_divisions.div_id"]]]]
                     ],
                     'as'=>'sports_data'
                   ]],
```

My expected output is:

```
  "booking": [
        {
            "booking_id": "5be015bd870565038c7660f3",
            "date": "2018-11-13 15:34:45",
            "sports_data": [
        "item_name" : "Football",
        "item_icon" : "ps_icon_football.png", 
        ]
        },
```

Comment: How are you initializing `$sports_data`? Please post that initialization line also.

Comment: Because your `foreignField` is an array of object that's why the ids will not match. You have to use newer `$lookup` syntax to `$unwind` the `sports_items` inside the `$lookup` pipeline.

Comment: `slot_divisions` does not appear to be an array. It would appear that you managed to name the keys `"0"` and `"1"` respectively. The `slots` in the other document is an example of what an "array" ( in what people other than the PHP world call an array ) should actually look like stored in MongoDB. You can do `"slot_divisions.0.div_id"` for example, but that would be beside the point since it's always pointing at the specific named key.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Can you pls check the updated query. Its still not working

Comment: Use below `$lookup` stage. `{
    $lookup: {
      from: "sports_items_collection",
      let: {
        "slot_id": "$slots.slot_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: "$slot_divisions"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$slot_divisions.div_id",
                "$$slot_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "sports_data"
    }
  }`

Comment: This:  ['$match'=>['$expr'=>['$in'=>['$slot_divisions.div_id', ['$slots.slot_id']]]]] somehow is not giving the required result @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: Could you post the expected output from the above collections.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet updated

Comment: @tyro please let me know if the below answer worked for you?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet custom query was working but when used with laravel syntax , it failed . To make it simpler, I added the sport_id in booking list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below aggregation

You can use new [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) syntax to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#lookup-multiple-joins) the foreign array inside the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) pipeline and then can easily [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#lookup-multiple-joins) with `ids`

```
db.bookings.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "sports",
    "let": { "slot_id": "$slots.slot_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$unwind": "$slot_divisions" },
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$slot_divisions.div_id", "$$slot_id"] }}},
      { "$project": { "item_name": 1, "item_icon": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "sports_data"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "booking_id": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$slots.booking_id", 0] },
    "date": 1,
    "sports_data": 1
  }}
])
```