# $lookup when foreignField is array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections, the first storing the animes watched by each user, their status etc:

```
const listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  animes: [{
    _id: false,
    anime: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'anime',
      unique: true
    },
    status: String,
    episodes: Number,
    rating: Number
  }]
});
```

and the second storing all animes and the relevant information.
I want to show that second collection but adding `status` and `episodes` fields that are filled from the list of the logged in user.

I tried the following:

```
Anime.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        'from': 'lists',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'animes.anime',
        'as': 'name'
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$animes'
    },
    {
      $project:{
        status:'$lists.animes.status'
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

but it returns an empty array.
I also don't know how to filter by `userId` seeing how the `_id` is in the foreign collection.

Comment: Because your `foreignField` is an array or objects you cannot get the matching documents

Comment: I thought `$unwind` would solve that. Any workaround please?

Comment: You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166680/lookup-when-foreign-field-is-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
{ "$lookup": {
  "from": "lists",
  "let": { "id": "$_id" },
  "pipeline": [
    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$$id", "$animes.anime"] }}},
    { "$unwind": "$animes" },
    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$animes.anime", "$$id"] }}}
  ],
  "as": "name"
}}
```

Comment: thanks! couldn't figure out what to use for `let` at first. 
It works, I just replaced the 2nd `$match` with `"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$user", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId)]}}` to select the user, nd now it works for all users. Thank you

Comment: variables taken in the `let` variable can be accessed inside the `$lookup` other wise you cannot. Just like in the above query we can access the `_id` inside the pipeline using `$$`. Have a look

Comment: so `let` lets you define foreign fields and then access them using `$` and `$$` for local fields? I think I understand now, thank you.