# $lookup foreignField from nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these 2 collections:

**power_usages_month**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1029d4a25f8180630896ad"), 
    "device_sn" : "ST9L0CY4A2AVY7HFWWUE", 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec823580cf34423ccb13d"), 
    "name" : "Lampu", 
    "current" : 0.6299, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(1040), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:04.403+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:04.403+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1029d4a25f8180630896ae"), 
    "device_sn" : "ST9L0CY4A2AVY7HFWWUE", 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec8eb580cf34423ccb13f"), 
    "name" : "Kipas Angin", 
    "current" : 0.1597, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(1040), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:04.404+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:04.404+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1029daa25f8180630896b1"), 
    "device_sn" : "ST9L0CY4A2AVY7HFWWUE", 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec823580cf34423ccb13d"), 
    "name" : "Lampu", 
    "current" : 0.7354, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(1040), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:10.400+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:10.400+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1029daa25f8180630896b2"), 
    "device_sn" : "ST9L0CY4A2AVY7HFWWUE", 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec8eb580cf34423ccb13f"), 
    "name" : "Kipas Angin", 
    "current" : 0.1365, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(1040), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:10.401+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-16T17:20:10.402+0000")
}
```

**users**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c64e4dd0a36b93c7deafa"), 
    "name" : "Asd", 
    "email" : "asd@asd.com", 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-13T20:43:00.871+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-13T23:08:26.149+0000"), 
    "family_members" : [
        //
    ], 
    "rooms" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c98826f0321f6986755da"), 
            "name" : "Ruang Makan", 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:14.839+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:14.840+0000"), 
            "devices" : [

            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c98876f0321f6986755dd"), 
            "name" : "Ruang Tamu", 
            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T00:23:19.693+0000"), 
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T19:00:08.281+0000"), 
            "devices" : [
                {
                    "serial_number" : "ST9L0CY4A2AVY7HFWWUE", 
                    "used_relay" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T16:56:22.156+0000"), 
                    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-14T16:56:22.156+0000"), 
                    "sensors" : [
                       //
                    ], 
                    "switches" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec823580cf34423ccb13d"), 
                            "name" : "Lampu", 
                            "relay" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "voltage" : 220.0, 
                            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-15T16:10:59.840+0000"), 
                            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-15T16:10:59.840+0000")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec8eb580cf34423ccb13f"), 
                            "name" : "Kipas Angin", 
                            "relay" : NumberInt(2), 
                            "voltage" : 220.0, 
                            "created_at" : ISODate("2020-07-15T16:14:19.181+0000"), 
                            "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-07-15T16:14:19.181+0000")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to join those two colletions using `$lookup` from `power_usages_month` referring to `rooms.devices.switches._id` from `users` collection. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022456/mongodb-lookup-on-nested-document), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919276/update-one-field-on-nested-array-document?noredirect=1#comment111268347_62919276), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911196/lookup-when-foreignfield-is-in-nested-array), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539509/lookup-when-foreignfield-is-array), but none of them results as i expected.

The desired result is to get to `voltage` and sum of `current` from `switches` array grouped by each `switch_id` like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec8eb580cf34423ccb13f"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec8eb580cf34423ccb13f"), 
    "device_sn" : "ST9L0CY4A2AVY7HFWWUE", 
    "sum_current" : <sum of current in corresponded switch_id>, 
    "voltage" : 220.0, 
    "watt" : <voltage * sum_current>
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec823580cf34423ccb13d"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5f0ec823580cf34423ccb13d"), 
    "device_sn" : "ST9L0CY4A2AVY7HFWWUE", 
    "sum_current" : <sum of current in corresponded switch_id>, 
    "voltage" : 220.0, 
    "watt" : <voltage * sum_current>
}
```

Query that i have tried:

```
db.getCollection("power_usages_month").aggregate([
            {
                "$lookup": {
//                    "localField": "switch_id",
                    "from": "users",
//                    "foreignField": "rooms.devices.switches._id",
                        "let": { "id": "$rooms.devices.switches._id" },
                        "pipeline": [
                            { "$unwind": "$rooms" },
                            { "$unwind": "$rooms.devices" },
                            { "$unwind": "$rooms.devices.switches" },                            
                            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$switch._id", "$$id"] }}},

                            {
                                "$project": { "rooms.devices.switches": 1 }
                            },
                            { "$group": { "_id":  "$rooms.devices.switches._id" }}
                          ],
                    "as": "switch"
                }
            },
            {
                "$unwind": "$switch"
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$switch._id",
                    "switch_id": { "$first": "$switch._id" },
                    "device_sn": { "$first": "$switch.device_sn" },
                    "current": {"$first": "$current"},
                    "sum_current": {
                        "$sum": "$current"
                    },
                    "voltage": { "$first": "$switch.voltage" },
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": 1,
                    "switch_id": 1,
                    "device_sn": 1,
                    "voltage": 1,
                    "current": 1,
                    "sum_current": 1,
                    "watt": { "$multiply": [ "$voltage", "$sum_current" ] }
                }
            }
        ])
```

I would appreciate your help..

Comment: To make things easier, please include the desired output in the question.

Comment: In the `$project` does it work if you replace `"name" : "$switches.name",` with `"name" : "$switches.rooms.devices.name",`

Comment: Please recheck my post, i updated the question and the desired result :)
I kinda tried the alternative way for the previous question, so i changed it to another question but the problem is still the same